# Use of Async Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Is there anyway to use AsyncTask without passing in any parameters? I am currently passing in an empty string, but I'm not doing anything with it:

```
    DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
    task.execute(new String[] { "" });

    class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainScreen.this);
     @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Gathering data for\n"+selectedSportName+".\nPlease wait...");
            dialog.show();
        }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //go do something
        return "";
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      dialog.dismiss();
      startTabbedViewActivity();
    }
}

private void startTabbedViewActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainScreen.this, TabbedView.class);
    intent.putExtra(SPORT_NAME_EXTRA, selectedSportName);
    intent.putExtra(HEADLINES_FOR_SPORT_EXTRA, existingSportHeadlines.get(selectedSportName));
    intent.putExtra(SCORES_FOR_SPORT_EXTRA, existingSportScores.get(selectedSportName));
    intent.putExtra(SCHEDULE_FOR_SPORT_EXTRA, existingSportSchedule.get(selectedSportName));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

For some reason, when I run the code as shown, with nothing happening in doInBackground(), the dialog dissapears, and the TabbedView activity starts.

But, when I use doInBackground() to run some code, the dialog dissapears, but, the TabbedView activity won't start. So I'm wondering if I could be doing anything differently?

Comment: For the first part of your question see my answer. For the second part, could you place a Breakpoint and see if `onPostExecute()` is called when you have code running in `doInBackground()`?

Comment: So what is the method signature for onPostExecute()? It's saying it has to override supertype, remove the @override annotation

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can use `AsyncTask` without passing a `String` to the `doInBackground()` method.

Just change the first and third generic types from `String` to `Void`:

```
class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

}
```

[From the doc:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:
>
> 1)Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
>
> 2)Progress, the type of the progress units published during the
>
> 3) background computation. Result, the type of the result of the
>   background computation.

For the signature of `onPostExecute`try this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

}
```

**EDIT**:

For the parameters it's actually very simple.

Consider this:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Type1, Type2, Type3> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Type3 doInBackground(Type1... param) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Type2... progress) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Type3 result) {
    }
}
```

In order to determine what *Type1*, *Type2* and *Type3* should be, you'll have to ask yourself 3 questions:

- What parameter should I pass to my task? => *Type1*
- What is the type of the intermediate results that need to be shown during processing? =>
  *Type2*
- What is the type of the resulting operation? => *Type3*

In your case, I don't know whether the URL that you are downloading data from is defined in a globally or you want to pass it to the task. If it's defined globally, then you don't *Type1* should be *Void*.

If you want to pass it to the task, then you can pass it to the `doInBackground()` method and *Type1* would be *String*.

Obviously for your case you don't need to worry about *Type2* since you aren't publishing any intermediate results and since you aren't doing anything with the result in `onPostExecute()` then `Type3` is `Void` too.

To summarize you'll have:

```
class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
         // do something with urls[0]
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
         // dismiss pd and start new intent
      }
}
```

Or:

```
class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
         // dismiss pd and start new intent
      }
}
```

Depending on your needs. Is that clear enough?

Comment: thats the thing, the background computation isn't returning anything, its modifying member variables in my class

Comment: so<String, Void, String> or <Void, Void, Void>?

Comment: <Void, Void, Void> with the signature that I have shown in my answer.

Comment: By the way for the first parameter it depends... Do you need to pass a URL to the doInBackground method? If that is the case then yes, keep it: <String, Void, Void>.

Comment: ok, so if nothing is returned to the task, how do I set it up, this is confusing. The only method that says it doesn't override supertype is protected String onPostExecute()

Comment: Let me try to explain very clearly. Just 1/2 minutes of writing :)

Comment: Well, I was only using this as an example. I'm not really 'donwloading webpage'. I just want to have the progress startup, use the doInBackground to update a HashMap in my class, and then start TabbedView activity, nothing in, nothing out. Plus, I've never heard of capital V void :-)

Comment: Yep. I get what you are saying. I've got it running, but, for some reason, when I use do in background to run a method, the Activity refuses to start. Just a blank screen. If I dont run the method, the activity starts fine.

Comment: Yes and that's probably because when you call `doInBackground`, `onPostExecuteù is probably never executed. What are you doing exactly in your `doInBackground` method? May be an exception is thrown?

Comment: I'm updating 3 hashmaps, by parsing an rss feed. I'm watching the LogCat and I see the data coming back, and when the app hangs, I'm not seeing any exceptions. And I'm pretty sure it's executing, because the dialog dismiss() is called in onPostExecute(), and It goes away.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10818/discussion-between-amokrane-chentir-and-johnny-rocket)

Answer (score 1):

You simple specify `Void` for `AsyncTask` generics

```
 class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
```

Look at the [AsyncTask generics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) section

Comment: this is the correct answer. note that you can also use anonymous class if you prefer to.